# Using sql to insert an xml attribute into an xml file

Tags: sql-server, xml, insert

Using Microsoft SQL Server Management Studio, I've inserted an element into the xml file and now wish to insert an attribute so it looks like:

`<a><b c="2"/></a>`

I created `b` with:

`update #tmp
  set column.modify('insert <b/> into (/a)[1]')`

Now I wish to create `c` as an attribute of `b` as shown above. So I try:

`update #tmp
  set column.modify('insert attribute c{''2''} into (/a/@b)[1]')`

But I get the error:

`XQuery [#tmp.column.modify()]: The target of 'insert into' must be an element/document node, found 'attribute(b,xdt:untypedAtomic)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`b` is an element, not an attribute, so you'll need to drop the `@`:

```
update #tmp
  set [column].modify('insert attribute c{''2''} into (/a/b)[1]');
```

[SqlFiddle here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/33537)

Comment: It works, thank you. I thought c is an attribute though? Do I have them flipped or something? What am I missing? I thought `b` was the element and what's inside would be an attribute?

Comment: `c` is an attribute, `b` is an element. The `into` bit requires an element target (as obviously we can't have attributes with attributes :-)